# Supporting enum arg from multiple definitions in C#

Tags: c#

I had a a code with a single enum definition like this in pseudo code:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum PetType
    {
        None,
        Cat = 1,
        Dog = 2
    }
}

class something..
{
    public PetType eF {set; get;}
}   

static void Main()
{
    somthing.eF = PetType.Cat;
}
```

Now I have a new enum and I want eF to be able to receive it also:

```
using System;

class Program
{
    enum PetType
    {
        None,
        Cat = 1,
        Dog = 2
    }

    enum SizeType
    {
        None,
        Big = 1,
        Small = 2
    }
}

class something..
{
    public PetType eF {set; get;} //what do I do here? chage the tyoe to enum? and then what??
}   

static void Main()
{
    somthing.eF = PetType.Cat;
    somthing.eF = SizeType.Big;
}
```

what do I do with eF so it can work with both enums?
I'm sorry if the question is dumb, but I could find any answer I could understand.

thanks,

Comment: The only way you can work with both enums is changing type of `ef` property to `int`.

Comment: You should have two separate properties for PetType and SizeType, why you are mixing these.

Answer (score 2):

You can't, and you shouldn't.

Enums are backed with `int`. If would be able to assign two enums with value `1`, it would have value `2`.

Just create two properties for the two enum types. Or better, use inheritance add add extra properties to specific deriving classes.

Answer (score 1):

As [Patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50249296/284240) has already told, you shouldn't mix two different things together, that can't work.

You *could* extend your `PetType` and remove `SizeType`, for example with `BigCat`,`SmallCat`,`BigDog`,`SmallDog`. But it was better if you had two properties in your class.

Consider that a `PetType` should be a class instead of an enum, because then it could have properties as well like `SizeType` and you had both informations in one property. Or add the `Size` and `PetType` to a class `Pet`. Your enums and classes could for example look like:

```
enum Pets
{
    None,
    Cat = 1,
    Dog = 2
}

enum Sizes
{
    None,
    Big = 1,
    Small = 2
}

class PetType
{
    public PetType(Pets type)
    {
        Type = type;
    }

    public Pets Type { get; set; } = Pets.None;
}

class Pet
{
    public Pet(PetType type, Sizes size)
    {
        Type = type;
        Size = size;
    }
    public PetType Type { set; get; }
    public Sizes Size { set; get; } = Sizes.None;
}

class SomeClass
{
    public Pet ThePet { get; set; }
}
```

Now you can create a big, fat cat in this way:

```
var bigFatCat = new SomeClass { ThePet = new Pet(new PetType(Pets.Cat), Sizes.Big)};
```